# Does redigo reconnects to the server?

Tags: go, redis

I am using [Redigo](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo) to connect to redis server through golang.

```
redisConnection, err = redis.Dial("tcp", "...")
redisConnection.Do(..., ...)
```

If I restart my server, I am unable to execute any command using the same `redisConnection`. Shouldn't it reconnect when I execute `Do` again?

Comment: What about  [redis golang](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sp0n-7/redis) library, how do we reconnect when redis server connection is lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your assumption is not correct. Using the `Dial` function it returns a single connection when the server terminates the connection, the client is not able to reconnect.
You should use `redis.Pool` and it should be able to auto-reconnect when you ask for a new connection, the function is: `pool.Get()`

Answer (score 0):

`redisConnection.Err()` returns a non nil value if the connection is not usable. We can `Dial` again in that case.